# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> While working on a Todo App

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to get data from a local API into my project, i am facing the following  problem:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final toDo = toDoFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

ToDo toDoFromJson(String str) => ToDo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String toDoToJson(ToDo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ToDo {
  ToDo({
    required this.id,
    required this.img,
    required this.name,
    required this.title,
    required this.done,
    required this.note,
    required this.priority,
    required this.dueDate,
    required this.taskOwner,
    required this.studentId,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  int id;
  String img;
  String name;
  String title;
  int done;
  String note;
  String priority;
  String dueDate;
  int taskOwner;
  String studentId;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  factory ToDo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ToDo(
        id: json["id"],
        img: json["img"],
        name: json["name"],
        title: json["title"],
        done: json["done"],
        note: json["note"],
        priority: json["priority"],
        dueDate: json["due_date"],
        taskOwner: json["TaskOwner"],
        studentId: json["studentId"],
        createdAt: json["createdAt"],
        updatedAt: json["updatedAt"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "img": img,
        "name": name,
        "title": title,
        "done": done,
        "note": note,
        "priority": priority,
        "due_date": dueDate,
        "TaskOwner": taskOwner,
        "studentId": studentId,
        "createdAt": createdAt,
        "updatedAt": updatedAt,
      };
}

Future<List<ToDo>> fetchTodos() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/task/all/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<ToDo> todo = toDoFromJson(response.body) as List<ToDo>;
    print(todo);
    return todo;
  } else {
    print("nothing found");
    return [];
  }
}
```

Json from API is as below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "img": "assets/images/user/user1.jpg",
    "name": "task 1",
    "title": "eee",
    "done": 0,
    "note": "eee",
    "priority": "Normal",
    "due_date": "2021-07-06T18:30:00.000Z",
    "TaskOwner": 1,
    "studentId": "2",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-26T14:39:54.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-26T14:39:54.000Z"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "img": "assets/images/user/user1.jpg",
    "name": "task 2",
    "title": "nnjn",
    "done": 0,
    "note": "2525",
    "priority": "High",
    "due_date": "2021-07-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "TaskOwner": 1,
    "studentId": "7",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-27T15:05:31.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-27T15:05:31.000Z"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "img": "assets/images/user/user1.jpg",
    "name": "task 3",
    "title": "5255",
    "done": 0,
    "note": "55",
    "priority": "Normal",
    "due_date": "2021-07-21T18:30:00.000Z",
    "TaskOwner": 1,
    "studentId": "7",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-27T15:05:48.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-27T15:05:48.000Z"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "img": "assets/images/user/user1.jpg",
    "name": "task 4",
    "title": "kaam kro",
    "done": 0,
    "note": "test note",
    "priority": "Normal",
    "due_date": "2021-07-21T18:30:00.000Z",
    "TaskOwner": 1,
    "studentId": "2",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-04T14:45:47.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-04T14:45:47.000Z"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to parse todos will return **a `ToDo` object** casted to a `List<ToDo>` which will cause an exception!

What you have to do is converting every single map in json to `ToDo` and then create a List from them.

Here is what you need to do:

replace this line

```
final List<ToDo> todo = toDoFromJson(response.body) as List<ToDo>;
```

with this:

```
final List<ToDo> todo =  List<ToDo>.from(response.body.map((x) => toDoFromJson(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed this by adding for loop to the Future function, refer to the code below -

```
    Future<List<ToDo>> fetchTodos() async {
  List<ToDo> todos = [];

  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://dhulltransport.com:20625/task/all/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for (var t in jsonList) {
      todos.add(ToDo.fromJson(t));
    }
    print(todos.length);
    return todos;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: take a look at my answer, it will make code more readable